# How to use several equal signs in text(x,y,expression(...))

Tags: r, graphics, plot, expression, plotmath

is there a solution to use more than one equals signs in a expression (which are not within brackets)? I'm currently doing it with " = ". But thats not so nice, since == and " = " look different on the plot.

Minimal sample:

```
plot(0:5,0:5, type="n")
saleprice <- 35
revenue <- 98000
text(1, 2, 
     bquote(paste(R(x[G]) == .(saleprice)%.%x[G], " = ", .(revenue))))
```

See the following image for the current status:
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsXbk.png)

I would like to use something like:

```
bquote(R(x[G]) == .(saleprice)%.%x[G] == .(revenue))
```

But it produces errors.

Comment: Huh, I never noticed before that R barfs on parsing chained comparison operators. It doesn't seem to mind anything else. Contrast `1 < 2 < 3` with `1 && 2 && 3`, `1 & 2 & 3`, or `x <- y <- z`, for example.

Comment: The reason why R doesn't like chained comparison operators is that ["it was decided that a == b == c would have undesirable
semantics"](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.general/326420)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `{}` to put an invisible grouping around the first equality.

```
text(1, 2, bquote({R(x[G]) == .(saleprice)%.%x[G]} == .(revenue)))
```