# How to use plotmath in R

Tags: r

```
DOLMin<-as.Date("2012-1-1")
DOLMax<-as.Date("2012-12-31")
title<-paste("Claims:",format.Date(DOLMin,"%b %Y"),"\u2264 DOL \u2264",format.Date(DOLMax,"%b %Y"))
plot(1:2,main=title)
```

The above code creates this meaningless plot
[image]

My problem is that I cannot build a pdf of this plot because of the way I'm generating my less than or equal to symbols.

How do I recreate the same title using plotmath?  Doing so will solve my pdf error issue which I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196086/r-plotting-a-less-than-or-equal-to-sign-and-saving-to-pdf-error?noredirect=1#comment31917832_21196086)

Comment: Well, read `?plotmath`.

Comment: @Roland I read ?plotmath and still could not figure out how to get my title the way I want it.  Can you provide a working solution for my question or at least give me a suggestion other than read ?plotmath

Comment: Thanks. I figure if neither I nor joran can do it without a search of more than the help page you ought to get credit for a relatively difficult question. I consider myself a power user of plotmath but I was stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *was* a little tricky:

```
a <- paste("Claims:",format.Date(DOLMin,"%b %Y"))
b <- format.Date(DOLMax,"%b %Y")
plot(1:2,main=bquote({.(a) <= DOL} <= .(b)))
```

I actually was not able to do this when I read your question. I figured it out by Googling and using the results from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4423130/324364) SO question and then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16919251/324364) one.